# Interfacing LAN9512 or LAN9514 to KSZ8895 Ethernet Switch for Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, lan

I would like to add `Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+` to my design.
My design has an ethernet switch `KSZ8895` on board. The 5th port can be configured for using `MII`.

It is known that the Compute Module (CM) provides Ethernet and USB via an IC. It is mostly `LAN9512 or LAN9514`. But, I am not sure whether I can directly interface LAN951x to one of the ports of `KSZ8895`. I don't want to use RJ45 to RJ45 connection to the switch via a short UTP cable, it is not desired as you may understand for a custom design.

I am also open to any other alternatives to `LAN951x` if it would be better for interfacing to `KSZ8895` while still providing internet to CM. In this case, I can volunteerly sacrifice USB option which `LAN951x` provides.

A piece of schematic from the switch circuit;

if possible, I like to interface `KSZ8895` without transformer `H1102NL`.

[image]

Comment: I would guess that over a short distance you don't need twisted pair cable.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit? I am not asking whether I can use a flat cable or twisted one. I am asking how I can interconnect the switch unit from one of the ports towards `LAN915x` on the same PCB with traces.

Comment: I thought you were asking whether you could use PCB traces instead of twisted-pair cable.